# Verify multiple contracts with hardhat

Tags: hardhat, verification

I've been developing projects with multiple contracts, that all talk to each other.

Is it possible to verify them all in a more effecient way?

I have been doing this

```
hh verify --network rinkeby <address> <parameters>
```